# How to add padding to ActionBar item

Tags: android, android-actionbar, padding

I searched for a solution for this and some people suggested that I include empty space when I am setting the action bar title like this:

```
actionBar.setTitle("   Ribbit");
```

It works fine, like this but I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving this, for example adding the android:padding xml attribute somewhere.

Comment: do you mean you would like to center the title of actionBar?

Comment: After MUCH research, I have discovered that it is possible to change the action bar title color by overriding the style in XML. I'm sure most/all properties can be changed this way, but the documentation is non-existent. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEST way is to use Material Design Toolbar widget.

create toolbar app_bar.xml file, you can give the name you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <!-- This textView will act as Title of page which you can make it Center or change padding/margin to change its position -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:text="Home"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Make sure, you selected theme in styles.xml with

```
"Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

after that, you need to initialize this toolbar in your mainActivity.xml layout file, for that include this,

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>
```

then in the MainActivity, you need to make instance of Toolbar toolbar. then,  after setContentView()
add following with your

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

make sure to disable

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();    
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

so it doesn't duplicate the titles of your toolbar and inherited one from app.

Comment: Thank you Ajay for the detailed and well explained answer. I will definitely try this approach! I assume that the toolbar widget automatically adds the necessary padding to the menu items.

Comment: yes it does automatically, but you can have your own textView as title of toolbar if you want , as given example above.

Answer (score 1):

> It works fine, like this but I was wondering if there is a better way
>   of achieving this, for example adding the android:padding xml
>   attribute somewhere.

Better way is for sure to **create custom layout (view)** for your ActionBar (rather now it should be called Toolbar since ActionBar is now deprecated).

With custom layout you can style your ActionBar as you wish. Possibilities are endless. 
[Here](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) is the point you can start with.

Comment: Thank you Ragnar your your answer! The link is definitely very helpful ! :)